# Can I pass a shared_ptr as a temporary to a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've this line in my code:

```
threads.emplace_back( scnThread, shared_ptr<wstring>( new wstring( nextFilePattern ) ), nextPathLength );
```

Can I rely on that the thread gets its copy of the shared_ptr before all shared_ptr-copies in the initiating thread are desroyed?

Comment: Yes, and not only you can, you have to. I 've seen many passing a reference that is to get out of scope before the thread finishes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is no issue here. The `std::thread` constructor always makes copies of the arguments passed to it (by copying or moving) and the thread executes with these copies as arguments. The copies are made in the context of the caller, not in another thread.

The `std::shared_ptr` temporary that you are passing to the constructor will live until the end of the full-expression, until after the thread constructor returns. It will be moved from to construct the thread function argument, so the reference count will stay 1 throughout all of it. The new thread starts executing only after this move is completed.